# Ubuntu and ubuntu-10.04 tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Wanted to create a synonym there but being a version synonym it's not possible for mortals. How are the policies about versions and softwares btw?

Answer (score 1):

For the big ones we seem to like a single monolithic tag for the entire product ([windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows)) and another tag for specific versions ([windows-2008-r2](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-2008-r2)). Same for the Linuxes out there. It gives the lazy an easy tag, allows the pedantic to cover all the bases, and allows people Interested in tags to just add one instead of an entire constellation.

Tag synonyms are odd. You need to meet some rep-requirements in-tag before you can suggest one, or enough rep overall (like 20K or better) to just do it to anything. In-tag rep is hard to get on SF outside of the big ones like [linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux) or [networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/networking).

If you see one that needs a synonym and you aren't able to suggest one, a meta-post is just fine to get the discussion started.

Comment: Can we have ubuntu and ubuntu-10.04 then?

Comment: @coredump We have ludid and lucid-lynx already as synonyms of 10.04. What did you want to add?

Comment: hmm. Ubuntu? But that may start to get confusing.

Comment: @coredump Yeah, we want to keep the 'Ubuntu' tag generic. Retaggers can add a version once it becomes clear which one the questioner is talking about.

Comment: I don't know if this is really a good idea. Tag wildcards like `windows-server-*` are a better approach. The [windows] tag is meaningless by itself, which means it's a meta-tag. If I spent HOURS cleaning the site of [vmware] you CANNOT tell me that [windows] is a good idea.

Comment: Windows is a better tag then Vmware.  Vmware is a company name not a product line.  If there was a `Microsoft` tag, it would be equivalent to Vmware.  A large number of the questions in the Windows tag apply to almost every version of Windows released in the last decade.  If we got rid of `Windows`, we should get rid of `linux` while we are at it.